# What is the best practice in ZF to collect, prepare and present the information for DB queries?

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, forms

I am new to Zend Framework and struggling with a problem that seems to be simple but hard to fix (at least for me).

I have a controller with an index and list actions. In index action, I am collecting the user input to build the query, prepare Db Select query and using session namespace to save it. In  list action, the query is retrieved from the session namespace and presented in grid.

The problem is that duplicating the web page in browser keeps the old session. What is the best way to solve this problem? I know that it is not a good practice to use sessions this way but can't figure out the alternative.

Here is what I want to achieve:

class QueryController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $form = new Application_Form_Query();
    $form->submit->setLabel('Search');
    $this->view->form = $form;  
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
       // here ideally I would like to redirect to listAction with $formData 
       // but don't know how to achieve that, 
       // with _forward it displays both form and the grid on the same page
       // this tip was provided by ArneRie (thanks ArneRie)
            }
   public function listAction()
   {
   //  I want this action to be called everytime after form input and  
   //  cycle without going back to form (indexAction)
   //  get the $formData from indexAction() or reposted in listAction()
   //  build query based on $formData
   //  display grid
   //  re-post data back to request object
   }
```

}

Note: any other suggestion, i.e, best practice with example, is welcomed.

Comment: why not build the query in list action? Pass the query parameters from index per post/get request to list..

Answer (score 0):

I assume that in index action You have form so why not point form's action to list controller to validate, prepare and make queries there?

Tell us what exactly You want to do, maybe We can find better solution.

**EDIT 21/12/2010**

```
class QueryController extends Zend_Controller_Action{

   public function indexAction()
   {
   $form = new Application_Form_Query();
   $form->submit->setLabel('Search');
   $form->setMethod('post')->setAction('/query/list');
   $this->view->form = $form;  


   }
   public function listAction()
   {
      $session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('queryssesion'); 
      if (!isset($session->query)) { $session->query = $YOUR_QUERY }
      $form = new Application_Form_Query();
      if ($this->getRequest()->isPost() && $form->isValid($_POST)) 
      {
          $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
          $session->query = $formData->query //example
      }
   }
}
```

This session thing should work, If not i think We can try with ajax and sending query as POST ;]

Comment: set $form->setAction('/query/list'), and validate data in list action, whats the problem?

Comment: Thanks Adam, I was not aware of setAction method. To complete my controller I need to ask one last thing. As the listAction displays grid from database query how would I repost the $formData inside listAction to itself on clicking paginator url (next/previous etc) links.

Comment: What is this for doing, what kind of data You send from it?
Is this form sends data witch is added to db or just controls what data get from db? If you use it to retrieve specific item from DB You can set method to GET and retrieve parameters from address on every page

Comment: Yes, I want to repost the $formData to listAction from within listAction. Don't want to use GET as $formData is a long array and the URL does not look nice either.
I have a Zend Paginator (inside My_Grid class) that displays the Zend_Db_Select instance. As the listAction is called iteratively due to Paginator pageControl, the query need to be built every time paginator next/previous links are clicked.

Comment: So We are running out of options :)

Have You tried to prevent session reset?
When query reach listAction You can save it to session as You done it before but with condition:  

$session = new Zend_Session_Namespace('queryssesion');
if (!isset($session->query))
{
$session->query = $YOUR_QUERY
}

And You have to remember to overwrite session when form data arrives   
I will edit my answer for better readability :)

Comment: Being on holiday break, back now. I am using the session exactly as you mentioned. Is it possible to create unique session so that duplication of "browser window/tab" could be identified? This way it will not be a required to go with post data.

Comment: If You have if (!isset($session->query)) { $session->query = $YOUR_QUERY } then on duplication of tab session will not be overwritten and no form resend will be necessary. Hope I understand what's the problem.